# rewrite some of the query strings with an exception condition

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm new to htaccess usage...

need help on the below

```
Form http://mysite.com/index.php?page=login to http://mysite.com/login
```

i used the following rule in htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
```

in the same, i have to restrict access to `mysite.com/admin` folder

meanwhile if i enter

```
 `http://mysite.com/admin` then it goes to `http://mysite.com/admin?page=admin`
```

i think this is bcoz of the above rule.

What i need is, if i enter `mysite.com/admin` that should go for `mysite.com/admin/index.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition for rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```